# Type 'MainMenu[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

To this day, I'm still fighting TypeScript issues.  At the moment, I'm unsure how to solve this one, even after all the Googling I've done.  I have the following code, but unsure how to solve the "never" issue.

```
const [documentMenu, setDocumentMenu] = useState([]);
const menu: MainMenu[] = [];
setDocumentMenu(menu);
```

What do I need to do here in order to solve the `Type 'MainMenu[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'`?

Comment: What's `setDocumentMenu`? Please include a [mre].

Comment: I have now updated the question.

Comment: The React `useState` hook is generic, you have to pass it a type parameter if you're not going to provide a specific init value for it to infer: `const [documentMenu, setDocumentMenu] = useState<MainMenu[]>([]);`

Comment: If you want the compiler to infer the type for you then you need to give it more of a hint. If you do `const [a, setA] = useState(1);` then the compiler can figure out it's a number. But an empty array could be anything, it just doesn't have enough info so you have to tell it, and the authors of @types/react put a generic type parameter in the signature so you could explicitly tell the compiler the type as I did in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set type for `useState()`

```
const [documentMenu, setDocumentMenu] = useState<MainMenu[]>([]);
const menu: MainMenu[] = [];
setDocumentMenu(menu);
```

If you create state like that without passing the type, TS will implicitly set the type from its usage, which is `[]` here. The type of `[]` is `never[]`. Hence the error.